# »Die Explosion war zu hören.« – What kind of sentence structure is this?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

What type of sentence structure is this (specifically, the “war ... zu hören”):

> Die Explosion war auf zwei Kilometer [Entfernung] zu hören.

When would one use it? I haven’t (consciously) seen it before, so is it commonly replaced with something else?

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple main clause with a predicative. You can tell those sentences by the special verbs *sein*, *werden* and *bleiben*, if used as full verbs. These three always need a predicative. (There are some more verbs which can go with predicatives, but these three are most common.)

Predicatives may be adjective phrases, nominative noun phrases, or verb phrases.

> Die Explosion war **sehr heftig**.
>
> Die Explosion war **eine Gefahr**.
>
> Die Explosion war **zu hören**.

The latter option does not exist in English —at least to my knowledge— , that's why it feels alien to you. English turns the verb phrase into an adjective phrase instead. This is possible in German, too, but it sounds awkward:

> Die Explosion war auf zwei Kilometer [Entfernung] **hörbar**.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with the meaning and what's behind that *sein*.

> Die Explosion war zu hören = man **konnte** die Explosion hören
>
> Das Formular ist auszufüllen = man **muss** das Formular ausfüllen;
>   das Formular **muss** ausgefüllt werden

See the modal verbs? They answer your question whether "it is commonly replaced with something else".

Now look at the English equivalent:

> The explosion **could** be heard.

See the modal verb here, too? Well, that's it. No reason to be astonished. ;-)

By the way. Sentences like *Die Explosion war noch in einer Entfernung von 20 Kilometern hörbar, auch die Erschütterungen waren dort spürbar.* are not awkward at all. :-)